# kivy-ios import ssl error when deploying to iOS

Tags: python, ios, ssl, kivy

I'm trying to import ssl in my kivy application and it crashes when I deploy to iOS.

It crashes on:

```
import ssl
```

This is the log from the device:

```
2013-07-31 20:13:06.215 mykivyapp[2568:907] [Springtomize]: Loading into sb-external process
2013-07-31 20:13:07.308 mykivyapp[2568:907] PythonHome is: /var/mobile/Applications/3742734C-18CB-49A5-B943-BABADBA9D26E/mykivyapp.app
2013-07-31 20:13:07.311 mykivyapp[2568:907] Initializing python
2013-07-31 20:13:07.719 mykivyapp[2568:907] Running main.pyo: /var/mobile/Applications/3742734C-18CB-49A5-B943-BABADBA9D26E/mykivyapp.app/YourApp/main.pyo
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.7.1
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 144 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <dds> ignored by config
[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <pygame> ignored by config
[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <pil> ignored by config
[DEBUG             ] [Image       ] option <gif> ignored by config
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_imageio, img_tex (img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG             ] [Text        ] Ignored <pygame> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdlttf(['text_pygame'] ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/0/Desktop/kivy-ios/app-mykivyapp/YourApp/main.py", line 30, in <module>
   File "/Users/0/Desktop/kivy-ios/build/python/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
     import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
 ImportError: No module named _ssl
2013-07-31 20:13:08.967 mykivyapp[2568:907] Application quit abnormally!
2013-07-31 20:13:09.016 mykivyapp[2568:907] Leaving
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mathieu Virbel  explained it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/kivy-users&hidesubject=true&hideforumtitle=true&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fkivy.org%2F%23#!searchin/kivy-users/RstDocument%2420in%2420iOS/kivy-users/CMO7sNez9Xs/RunwL_mtoQEJ) you need to find a way to import your ssl module in your project.